# JPA doesn't save the Associated Object in Object gotten by @RequestBody annotation

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

following is `Developer` Entity.

- `Developer`

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Developer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="DEVELOPER_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String nickname;
    private String name;
    private String imageURI;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "developer", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addArticle(Article article) {
        this.articleList.add(article);

        if ( article.getDeveloper() != this )
            article.setDeveloper(this);
    }

}
```

and following is `Article` Entity.

- `Article`

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ARTICLE_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String subject;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> contents = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addContent(String content) {
        this.contents.add(content);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="DEVELOPER_ID")
    private Developer developer;

    public void setDeveloper(Developer developer) {
        this.developer = developer;

        if ( !developer.getArticleList().contains(this) )
            developer.getArticleList().add(this);
    }

}
```

view request to RestController (/about/developers/rest/add) via ajax.
and following is Request Body's json.

- request body json

```
    [
    {"articleList":[
        {"contents":["article line","article line"],
        "subject":"article subject"},
        {"contents":["article line","article line","article line"],
        "subject":"article subject"}
     ],
    "nickname":"dev nickname",
    "name":"(dev name)",
    "imageURI":"default.png"
    },

    {"articleList":[
        {"contents":["article line","article line"],
        "subject":"article subject"},
        {"contents":["article line"],
        "subject":"article subject"}
     ],
    "nickname":"dev nickname",
    "name":"(dev name)",
    "imageURI":"default.png"}
    ]
```

RestController that including `@RequestBody`

- `RestController`

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/about")
public class AboutRestController {

    @Autowired
    private DeveloperService developerService;

    @PostMapping("/developers/rest/add")
    public void developersRegisterAPI(@RequestBody List<Developer> developerList) {

        /** Not Working **/
        // Saving Developer only (except Associated Articles)
        for (Developer developer : developerList) {
            developerService.save(developer);
        }


        /** Working **/
        // Saving Developers and Associated Articles
        for (Developer developer : developerList) {

            Developer newDeveloper = new Developer();
            newDeveloper.setName(developer.getName());
            newDeveloper.setImageURI(developer.getImageURI());
            newDeveloper.setNickname(developer.getNickname());

            for (Article article : developer.getArticleList()) {

                Article newArticle = new Article();
                newArticle.setSubject(article.getSubject());
                newArticle.setContents(article.getContents());
                newDeveloper.addArticle(newArticle);

            }

            developerService.save(newDeveloper);
        }
    }

}
```

when i printed `@RequestBody List<Developer> developerList`, each `Developer` object has associated `Article` objects.

in first case (not working properly, `developerService.save(developer);`), `developerService.findAll()`'s result including only `Developer` Objects. there are not `Article` objects in retrieved `Developer` objects.

in second case (working properly, `developerService.save(newDeveloper);`), `developerService.findAll()`'s result including both `Developer` Objects and associated `Article` objects.

**in fact, both cases are saving associated `Article`s in RestController's method.
but in web controller's method, when i used `developerService.findAll()`, there aren't articles. so if i passed retrieved `Developer` Objects via `Model`, there aren't Associated `Article` and view can not print these objects.**

and following is `DeveloperService`

- `DeveloperService` and `DeveloperRepository`

```java
@Service
public class DeveloperService {
    @Autowired
    DeveloperRepository developerRepository;

    public void save(Developer developer) {
        developerRepository.save(developer);
    }

    public void delete(Developer developer) {
        developerRepository.delete(developer);
    }

    public List<Developer> findAll() {
        return developerRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface DeveloperRepository extends JpaRepository<Developer, Long> {
}
```

and following is `ARTICLE` Table in `h2-console`

[ARTICLE Table in h2-console (click me for image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0h2m.jpg)

as you can see, `DEVELOPER_ID` is null.

can i fix this only using

```java
        for (Developer developer : developerList) {
            developerService.save(developer);
        }
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first will not work because in Articles list in json does not have Developer Object bound. the second case is working because of this line

```
    newDeveloper.addArticle(newArticle);
```

in which you are adding 
        if ( article.getDeveloper() != this )
            article.setDeveloper(this);
try to bind developer object in your article list in the first loop and your code will work. i mean try to bind developer object in each article object from the list

Comment: it make sense. there are difference between
```newDeveloper.addArticle(newArticle);```

and maden Object by MessageConverter? 

these Object has same values. but after persist, in ARTICLE Table, 

```newDeveloper.addArticle(newArticle);``` has 'DEVELOPER_ID', whereas MessageConverter Object doesn't (null value).